# I have a problem in sdk component Installation. Can anyone help me to resolve these issues?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, sdk

I am very beginner to android studio, and I want to install android studio latest version 11.0.12. on my windows 10.You can see in the attached screenshot.

[image]

Its showing multiple errors while installing. I have to install command line tool but android studio does not showing this tool to install. Flutter doctor in cmd demands to approve flutter license. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can check the second box and Refresh on better net connection

Answer (score 0):

You already have installed Android SDK build tools in your android studio, you can see in the screenshot uploaded in your question. It seems everything is okay and you are ready to start work on flutter and even without that you are good to go for development. Hope to have a good development career ahead.